# selecting a value to declare in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I'm very new to Perl.

Let say the output from command would be as below,

```
AMQ8409: Display Queue details.
   QUEUE(SYSTEM.DATATYPE.REPLY.QUEUE)      TYPE(QLOCAL)
   ACCTQ(QMGR)                             ALTDATE(2016-08-01)
   ALTTIME(18.33.20)                       BOQNAME( )

AMQ8409: Display Queue details.
   QUEUE(SYSTEM.DATATYPE.REQUEST.QUEUE)    TYPE(QLOCAL)
   ACCTQ(QMGR)                             ALTDATE(2016-08-01)
   ALTTIME(18.32.37)                       BOQNAME( )

AMQ8409: Display Queue details.
   QUEUE(SYSTEM.MESSAGE.ASSOCIATION.QUEUE)
   TYPE(QLOCAL)                            ACCTQ(QMGR)
   ALTDATE(2016-08-01)                     ALTTIME(18.32.37)

AMQ8409: Display Queue details.
   QUEUE(SYSTEM.PENDING.DATATYPE.REPLY)        TYPE(QLOCAL)
   ACCTQ(QMGR)                             ALTDATE(2016-08-01)
   ALTTIME(18.33.20)                       BOQNAME( )
```

I plan to store value under QUEUE section which the value contain 'DATATYPE' word and not contain 'REPLY' word, the desire output would be,

> SYSTEM.DATATYPE.REQUEST.QUEUE

My code as follow,

```
while (<OPEN_FILE>) {
      my ($QName1) = /QUEUE\(([^()]+)\)/;
      my ($QName1) = $QName1 =~ m/DATATYPE/ && $QName1 !~ m/RETRY/;

      print "$QName1 \n";
}
```

However, above code failed.

Before above code, I try to declare using one single line but not success at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
^\s*QUEUE\(\K(?=.*DATATYPE)(?!.*REPLY)[^\)]*
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ks7qEo/1)

Sample Code: ( [Run it here](http://ideone.com/eZy2z4) )

```
my $regex = qr/^\s*QUEUE\(\K(?=.*DATATYPE)(?!.*REPLY)[^\)]*/mp;     
if ($yourstring =~ /$regex/g ) {
  print ${^MATCH};
}
```